# How to show the similarity notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition, math-history, mathematical-modeling

I have defined a similarity measure $U_{sim}(T_t,T_{t-1})$ which is the similarity metric between two items. Now I wanna show the the similarity between $T_t$ and all previous $T_i$s. I represented like this:

$$\bigcup^{t-1}_{i=1}U_{sim}(T_t,T_i)$$

in which the output is a set of real values. Is this correct?

What other notations normally is used in mathematics for similarity? I did not know that is why I showed with $U_{sim}$

Comment: A binary relation on a set $X$ is some (any)  $E\subseteq X\times X,$ and x\sim y or x\equiv  y or x=_E y or xEy are often used  to mean $(x,y)\in E$. (Even set-theorists prefer to write $x<y$ rather than $(x,y)\in <$.) But I dk what a similarity metric is.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet my question is only what notation (letter, or greek letter) normally is used for similarity? your response is not helpful. thanks anyway

Comment: His response was not helpful because your description is not clear. "Similarity" means different things in mathematics, depending on the objects being compared and what comparisons you are making. On the other hand "measure" and "metric" both are used for very specific - but different - things. Yet you use both to describe the same thing. Further, both measures and metrics take real numbers as values, while apparently your $U_{sim}$ has sets for values, since you union them together.  If you have a source for these concepts, follow their lead, if not please explaim more.